# Issue with Javascript loop

Tags: javascript

My div class array looks like this

`[ <div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​A​</div>​ ,
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​W​</div>​ , 
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​E</div>​ , 
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​AA</div>​ ]`

I have this javascript function

```
var products= document.getElementsByClassName("divtitle")[0].innerHTML;
return products;
```

But now i have more than 1 product name in the div and i am wondering how to write loop in JavaScript using this function.

```
var products= document.getElementsByClassName("divtitle").innerHTML;
var arrayLength = products.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
return products[i];
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: The return statement will stop the execution of the for loop on the first iteration.

Comment: @hopeless, how do i fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do still, perhaps you can edit your question to provide a little more context? A good place to start would be by adding some more code around the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div innerHTML looks something like this "product1, product2, product3.." when you get it products will be a string, and not a list.

When you loop over string length you actually loop over its characters.
Try to do something like this:

```
var products= document.getElementsByClassName("divtitle").innerHTML;
return products.split(",")
```

If you separate different products with comma, this should return a list of products.

PS. your question is a little unclear, it would help a lot if you show an example of the html elements, eg how divtitle looks like.

Comment: my div class looks like this [
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​A​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​W​</div>​
, 
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​E</div>​
, 
<div class=​"divtitle" style=​"height:​ 22px;​">​AA</div>​
]

Comment: you should probably add it to your question inside a codebox

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the entire product array within your for loop. you need to write something like this:

```
var products= document.getElementsByClassName("divtitle").innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  /*you will write your code that you want to do with each product here
    using the i index, such as: */
  console.log(products[i])
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…). And i only want it to return the products, so i added return products[i];